# How do I fix a leaking ceramic mono sink mixer?

Tags: plumbing, leak, kitchens

We have a kitchen mixer tap something like the one below. It's white and has 1/4 turn ceramic taps (so not like the taps in the one below in that respect). The taps are not leaking, the mixer is leaking where the neck of the mixer meets the body of the block.

Is this serviceable, and if so, how to I remove the neck/arm part that swings left and right from the main body of the mixer block to repair the seal or replace a washer?

[image: Example Mixer Tap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the rear of the unit there is a screw. NB. it might not be visible or even tactile if it's been painted over. Look carefully and scratch at any thick paint to reveal a small retaining screw. Remove the screw so that the neck can be pulled vertically out of the base. There are O-rings in grooves in the neck of the tap that can be easily replaced.

If, like me, you cut the pipes to remove the tap and then find, once you've made this a proper plumbing job, only to find a simple screw that solves the problem you might just kick yourself for not checking here first. We live and learn eh.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to take the whole tap off the sink and access the washers from the base.

Comment: Oh dear - I feared that might be the case. The pipes go directly up into the mixer tap and there are no isolation valves to turn off before the operation. Sigh.

Comment: If that is the case, it is probably a good idea to turn off the main water supply and retrofit some shut off valves.